# Can I declare android:id as array in Android?

Tags: java, android, layout

I have this code.

```
rele[0] = new ReleController(findViewById(R.id.button1), 1, this);
rele[1] = new ReleController(findViewById(R.id.button2), 2, this);
rele[2] = new ReleController(findViewById(R.id.button3), 3, this);
rele[3] = new ReleController(findViewById(R.id.button4), 4, this);
```

And my button layout looks like:

```
<LinearLayout style="@style/CoreLayout">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/Button.Blue"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_arrow_left" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@style/Button.Green"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_arrow_right"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout style="@style/CoreLayout">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="@style/Button.Yellow"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_arrow_up"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="@style/Button.Purple"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_arrow_down"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am trying to figure if there is a way to do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  rele[i] = new ReleController(findViewById(R.id.button[i+1]), i+1, this);
}
```

In real, I have 8 buttons, so it is really annoying to write all these lines for all buttons.

I am wondering if the button IDs can be declared as array like this:

```
android:id="@+id/button[1]"
android:id="@+id/button[2]"
android:id="@+id/button[3]"
...
```

Thank you for all your answers.

Comment: no ..... but you can use `int[] = {R.id.1, R.id.2, R.id.N}`

Comment: Maybe you mean something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642104/array-of-buttons-in-android [Check the most valued answer]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an array to store the id of views. Just declare your array like this:

```
int[] buttonId = new int[] { R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3, R.id.button4 }
```

Then iterate through it.

Comment: If the functionality what I was looking for is not implemented in Android, this is the best option. Thank you really much. Shame on me I have not figured this myself :).

Comment: If it's too annoying to "write all these lines" have a look at ButterKnife. It often saves alot of typing when finding and binding views. http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/