# How to define an array of buttons in Android activity_main.xml

Tags: java, android

Right now I have the following code in "activity_main.xml" :

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Table_Button_1_1"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:text="@string/Table_Button_1_1"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Table_Button_1_2"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="102dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:text="@string/Table_Button_1_2"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Table_Button_1_3"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="199dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:text="@string/Table_Button_1_3"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

...

In the Java code it looks like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button_1_1 = findViewById(R.id.Table_Button_1_1);
    button_1_1.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
    button_1_1.setTextSize(23);
    button_1_1.setText("2 \u24be\n\u2665 \u2709");

    Button button_1_2 = findViewById(R.id.Table_Button_1_2);
    button_1_2.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
    button_1_2.setTextSize(23);
    button_1_2.setText("a b\nc d");
```

With lots of buttons, I want to access them through an array of buttons, so I want my Java code to look like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
  Button myButton[]=new Button[6];

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    for (int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
      Button myButton[i] = findViewById(R.id.Table_Button[i]);    <-- Get the button Like this
      myButton[i].setText("Text : "+i);
    }
  }
```

...

Yet, I don't know how to define the button array in activity_main.xml, so that in Java I can access them through findViewById(R.id.Table_Button[i]), I guess something like this :

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/Table_Button[6]"                  <--- ?
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:text="@string/Table_Button[6]"             <--- ?
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

This will also affect string.xml. What's the proper way to do it [ in both activity_main.xml & string.xml ] ?

Edit : Here is why my question is different from suggested previous question. The first half is similar [ how to access the buttons from java code ], but I want the buttons to be defined in the activity_main.xml, so at design time, I can see their layout, and locate which button is in which row,col. Therefore what I wanted the most is "How to define the button array in the activity_main.xml & string.xml" and be able to access them from the java code ?

Comment: U can define all the buttons programmatically, suppose have a LinearLayout in ur XML as root, and in ur java file add as many buttons as u want in that linearlayout. u can also loop through all the views in LinearLayout in future.

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642104/array-of-buttons-in-android

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array of Buttons in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642104/array-of-buttons-in-android)

Comment: You can't do it this way.